# Error: package or namespace load failed occurrs in RStudio but not in R console

Tags: r, ubuntu, rstudio, conda, rgdal

While working in a conda environment, I have been observing an unexpected behavior with R>=4.1.3. Namely, in terminal I can launch R and load GDAL-based libraries

```r
R version 4.1.3 (2022-03-10) -- "One Push-Up"
Copyright (C) 2022 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-conda-linux-gnu (64-bit)

... STANDARD R MESSAGE ...

> library(sf)
Linking to GEOS 3.11.1, GDAL 3.6.2, PROJ 9.1.0; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
```

but in RStudio I get the error below

```r
R version 4.1.3 (2022-03-10) -- "One Push-Up"
Copyright (C) 2022 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-conda-linux-gnu (64-bit)

... STANDARD R MESSAGE ...

> library(sf)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘sf’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/home/ivan/miniconda3/envs/r41_dev/lib/R/library/sf/libs/sf.so':
  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.30' not found (required by /home/ivan/miniconda3/envs/r41_dev/lib/R/library/sf/libs/../../../../libgdal.so.32)
```

Even though the behavior in terminal suggested that the package `libstdc++` was installed, I have reinstalled it from [the Gnome repo](https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/20.04/ubuntu-updates-main-amd64/libstdc++6_10.3.0-1ubuntu1%7E20.04_amd64.deb.html). The package is definitely installed on my machine.

```bash
apt list --installed | grep libstdc++ 

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

libstdc++-8-dev/focal,now 8.4.0-3ubuntu2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libstdc++-9-dev/focal-updates,focal-security,focal-security,now 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libstdc++6/focal,now 11.1.0-1ubuntu1~20.04 amd64 [installed]
libstdc++6/focal,now 11.1.0-1ubuntu1~20.04 i386 [installed,automatic]
```

The Rstudio version is

```r
RStudio 2022.07.2+576 "Spotted Wakerobin" Release (e7373ef832b49b2a9b88162cfe7eac5f22c40b34, 2022-09-06) for Ubuntu Bionic
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) QtWebEngine/5.12.8 Chrome/69.0.3497.128 Safari/537.36
```

And here the session info

```r
>  sessionInfo()
R version 4.1.3 (2022-03-10)
Platform: x86_64-conda-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS/LAPACK: /home/ivan/miniconda3/envs/r41_dev/lib/libopenblasp-r0.3.21.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=de_DE.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=de_DE.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=de_DE.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] compiler_4.1.3     magrittr_2.0.3     class_7.3-21       DBI_1.1.3          tools_4.1.3        units_0.8-1       
 [7] proxy_0.4-27       Rcpp_1.0.10        KernSmooth_2.23-20 grid_4.1.3         e1071_1.7-13       classInt_0.4-8
```

I have been using conda environments with RStudio for a while and I have come across multiple challenges but I don't seem capable to come around this one.

Can anyone help me understand how come RStudio cannot access this package while R can access it from terminal?

As as side note, the problem does not occur with R=4.0.5 and, to the best of my knowledge, did not occur with R=4.1 either. I certainly have update apt multiple times, but I cannot recall any major update to my system.

EDIT TO ADDRESS THE POINTS RAISED BY @merv IN COMMENTS

I have created several environments with different R versions in the attempt to frame and solve this problem, without success.

I've now followed these steps:

1. check conda version with `conda -V`, returns `conda 22.11.1`
2. create a fresh environment with `conda create -n r41_test -c conda-forge r-base=4.1.3 r-sf -y`
3. activate the environment with `conda activate r41_test`
   1 save the `conda list` output to file and share it [through this link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/IvanPalm/code_snippets/main/r41_test_conda_list)
4. launch R from terminal
5. load the sf library with `library(sf)`, the library loads without issues
6. close R with `q()` and type `n` to avoid workspace image to be saved
7. launch RStudio by typing `rstudio` (from the activated environment)
8. load library sf with `library(sf)` from the R console in RStudio, the library fails loading with the same error reported above.

While running this test, I have noticed something I had not noticed before: when the conda environment at step 2, the following message was printed, but the environment was successfully create. I could also activate it, launch R from terminal, and load the library despite the `SafetyError`.

```bash
Downloading and Extracting Packages

Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: | 
SafetyError: The package for r-base located at /home/ivan/miniconda3/pkgs/r-base-4.1.3-h2f963a2_5
appears to be corrupted. The path 'lib/R/doc/html/packages.html'
has an incorrect size.
  reported size: 3061 bytes
  actual size: 55120 bytes


done
```

Previous my post, I have tried this procedure also on another laptop running Ubuntu 20.04. I barely use that machine so it may serve as an 'independent control'. I am not sure whether the `SafetyError` was thrown also there, but RStudio failed to load the package also on that machine.

Comment: I cannot recreate this. Creating an environment with `-c conda-forge r-base=4.1.3 r-sf` give `sf=1.0_7` and the environment also installs `libstdcxx-ng`, which is what provides the `libstdc++.so.6` that `ldd` resolves during library loading. Maybe give us more detail about how RStudio is launched with the environment and perhaps an abridged summary of the `conda list` for the environment. You may also want to update RStudio. Also, is it possible you have some user-level package installs that might be interfering? I.e., you did `install.packages` at some point?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time, @merv. I've repeated the procedure and updated the question. I'd like to draw your attention on the `SafetyError` thrown while creating the conda env. Could that be related to the issue with RStudio?

Comment: Thanks for the updated information. I wouldn’t expect the SafetyError to be the issue, but you’d likely need to remove that `r-base` from the package cache and redownload  it (recreate environment) if you’d like to fix that. What does `rstudio` point at in the shell? Could you share `which rstudio` or `type rstudio`?  Also, can you check `env` for any R-related variables being defined?  I’m still suspicious that there is some non-Conda cache of packages.

Comment: @merv. Removing the corrupted `r-base=4.1.3` from `miniconda3/pkgs/` resolved the `SafetyError` but not the `package or namespace load failed`, as you anticipated. Thank you.

As for your question, I typically have only one version of RStudio installed on my machine, and I launch it from different conda environments. Under this setup, `which rstudio` or `type rstudio` could only point at the directory `/usr/bin/rstudio`.

Comment: I have now created another test environment (as reported above), but I added one step: installing RStudio with `conda install -c conda-forge rstudio-desktop`. 
This solved the issue, but I don't understand why. Can you help understand why the RStudio installed on my system could not pick up anymore some of the packages installed the activated conda environment? And also, can you suggest how to reconfigure RStudio so that I don't need to install it in every R environment I generate? Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure what else to check. Maybe check for any of the files in [this thread](https://support.posit.co/hc/en-us/articles/360047157094-Managing-R-with-Rprofile-Renviron-Rprofile-site-Renviron-site-rsession-conf-and-repos-conf). Or possibly any `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: Ok, I will check that out. Thank you, @merv, for the hints provided. Much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is because rstudio installed via deb packages does not use the `libstdc++.so` from the conda environment.

Try with:

```
conda activate my-env
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/envs/my-env/lib/
rstudio
```

Comment: Spot on! Thank you for the hint @Peter. This behavior is new to me. I used to launch rstudio installed via deb packages and the directory of the conda environment was picked up automatically. I wonder what cause this to change

Comment: @IvanP I have the same feeling! Never had this issue a year ago. But maybe my Linux system is now old enough to not have the latest libstd++, which is used in the conda build process..